# Implementing RBAC, the default user still retains access even after applying roleBinding

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to implement RBAC for each user. Already have OIDC running and I can see my user credentials being saved in kube config. 
But to check my rolebindings, i have to run the command as 
`kubectl get pods --as=user@email.com`, even though I am logged in as user@email.com (through gcloud init).
I am an owner account in our cloud but I was assuming the RBAC limitations should still work.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from credentials, you should configure a kubectl context to associate this credentials with the cluster. And to set it as the default context:

First, list kubectl clusters with `k config get-clusters`

Then create a new context:

```
kubectl config set-context my-new-context --cluster <CLUSTER NAME> --user="user@email.com"
```

And finally configure the new context as default:

```
kubectl config use-context my-new-context
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the same in minikube as well as my cloud cluster. Minikube. It says "error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)". I am not sure, but the email account is the same that I use to login in google console and the OIDC for the email is also provided by google. I haven't even applied any rolebindings yet. Was just checking if it works

Comment: It means that the problem is at authentication level, can we see the kubeconfig file? (Alter any personal data)

Answer (score 0):

> I am an owner account in our cloud but I was assuming the RBAC limitations should still work.

RBAC is additive only. If you have permissions via another configured authorizer, you will still have those permissions even if you have lesser permissions via RBAC.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try now with a user account with much lesser permissions and add specific RBAC permissions to it.